# Fooling around with xml

Tags: php, html, xml

I have this really poorly formed xml that in php I am able to get the contents of, the problem is that it strips the html tags

```
<content>
    <WhatsHere>
    <![CDATA[
            <h1>Content</h1>
    ]]>
    </WhatsHere>
    <WhatsComing>
    <![CDATA[
            <h2>I have no idea</h2>
    ]]>
    </WhatsComing>
</content>
```

I am essentially doing:

```
class CoreTheme_AdminPanel_Template_Helper_GrabUpdateContent{

    private $_xml_object_content = null;

    public function __construct(){
        if($this->_xml_object_content === null){
            $this->_xml_object_content = simplexml_load_file('http://adambalan.com/aisis/aisis_update/Test/update_notes.xml');
        }
    }

    public function whats_here(){
        $content = $this->_xml_object_content->WhatsHere[0];
        echo $content;
        return trim($content);
    }

}
```

When you call `whats_here()` you get `<p>content</p>` instead of `<h1>content</h1>` like you should.

Comment: my question is as clear as it gets.

Comment: `Fooling around with xml` is not realy explaining what your problem is. You could read [this](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10647/how-do-i-write-a-good-title) to inprove the change for an answer from someone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like [this comment](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-file.php#61450) in the PHP help page for **simplexml_load_file** may apply to you, saying:

> So it seems SimpleXML doesn't support CDATA...